# How Do I Get TikZ Graphics While Keeping Alternating Page Margins in Book documentclass?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, geometry, books

I'm trying to typeset a book in which the only content on every page is a TikZ diagram. I want the diagram to fill all of the available page space, so I'm using custom margins via the geometry package. The first page of the document looks about like I want and I expected the second page to look like a mirror image, but that's not what I get. The first page has a much larger left margin than right margin, but the second page's left and right margins look about equal.

Below is my code, stripped down to the bare essentials to illustrate the problem. To keep the code brief, I've just shaded where the diagram would be rather than including the whole of the diagram.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage[top=0.1cm, bottom=0.1cm, inner=0.6cm, outer=0.106cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\picturewidth{580pt}
\newcommand\pictureheight{788pt}
\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{0.8}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (0pt,0pt);
\fill [mygray](0pt,0pt) rectangle (\picturewidth,\pictureheight);
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (0pt,0pt);
\fill [mygray](0pt,0pt) rectangle (\picturewidth,\pictureheight);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Does putting `\centering` after `\begin{document}` give you what you want?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! it got me 90% of the way to where I was trying to go, but John Kormylo's response really got me all the way there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to overlap the margins than change them.  Don't forget to run twice.

If you are going to put these in floats, you need to use the `ifoddpage` package, as `\value{page}` is not reliable.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{book}
%\usepackage[top=0.1cm, bottom=0.1cm, inner=0.6cm, outer=0.106cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{0.8}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\ifodd\value{page}
  \fill [mygray] ($(current page.south west)+(0.6cm,0.1cm)$) rectangle
    ($(current page.north east)+(-0.106cm,-0.1cm)$);
\else
  \fill [mygray] ($(current page.south west)+(0.106cm,0.1cm)$) rectangle
    ($(current page.north east)+(-0.6cm,-0.1cm)$);
\fi
\end{tikzpicture}
\newpage

\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\ifodd\value{page}
  \fill [mygray] ($(current page.south west)+(0.6cm,0.1cm)$) rectangle
    ($(current page.north east)+(-0.106cm,-0.1cm)$);
\else
  \fill [mygray] ($(current page.south west)+(0.106cm,0.1cm)$) rectangle
    ($(current page.north east)+(-0.6cm,-0.1cm)$);
\fi
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That looks like it solved it, thanks a lot!